# How can I write this query in Codeigniter Model?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

```
SELECT user_name, user_dept, user_level
FROM tbl_users
WHERE (user_dept = 'Admin' AND user_level = '2') OR (user_level = '3');
```

I need to write this in CI Model function. What I tried is

```
function getForwardvalues($uname)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('user_name')->from('tbl_users')->where('user_dept'= $uname && 'user_level'='2')->or_where('user_level'='3')->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I tried this as well but i didnt get what i wanted

```
function getForwardvalues($uname)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('user_name')
        ->from('tbl_users')
        ->group_start()
        ->where('user_dept =', $uname)
        ->where('user_level=', '2')
        ->group_end()
        ->or_where('user_level=','3')
        ->get();
    
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function getForwardvalues($uname)
{

    $this->db->select('user_name, user_dept, user_level');
    $this->db->from('tbl_users');
    $this->db->where('(user_dept = "'.$uname.'" AND user_level = 2)')->or_where('user_level', 3);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: What if I want to pass $uname to that "Admin" in where clause?

Comment: @AB D what you actually want??

Comment: KUMAR I need to pass the argument @uname to "Admin" How?

Comment: ok. ill change the word admin with the $uname in my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
function getForwardvalues($uname)
{

$user_dept="Admin";
$user_level="3"; 

$query = $this->db->select("user_name, user_dept, user_level")
        ->from("tbl_users")
        ->where("user_dept",$user_dept)
        ->where("user_level",$user_level)
        ->or_where("user_level ",'3')
        ->get();

 return $query->result();
 
 }
```

Comment: No, This does not retrieve the first AND where clauses.. only does retrieve condition after or_where