# how to write this query in Codeigniter "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE user_name='".$email."' AND password='".$password."'";

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to write this query in Codeigniter

```php
"SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE user_name='".$email."' AND password='".$password."'";
```

Comment: or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494587/how-can-i-write-this-query-in-codeigniter-model

Comment: **it's all in the documents**, just have a look at Query Builder in CI 3.x https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html or CI 4.x: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html also important to read about **query binding**, see those docs for details

Answer (score 2):

As codeigniter Docs ([Here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)):

```php
$query = $this->db->get_where('login', ['user_name' => $email, 'password' => $password]);
$row = $query->row();
```

Comment: And remember to load database in the model: `$this->load->database();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name='".$email."' AND password='".$password."'");
```

[Refer Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)